# I m receiving a Type error when i m trying to connect mysql database with tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

MY CODE-

```
import tkinter as tk

import mysql.connector

# SQL CONNECTION
try:
    data = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="login cred")
    cursor = data.cursor()
    print("Connection Successful")
except:
    print("Not Successful")

# GUI CREATION
registration_window = tk.Tk()
registration_window.geometry("1000x500")
registration_window.title("Register Yourself")

# TEXT BOX
firstname = tk.Entry(registration_window, show=None)
lastname = tk.Entry(registration_window, show=None)
email = tk.Entry(registration_window, show=None)
password = tk.Entry(registration_window, show="*")


# DATABASE
def insert():
    FirstName = firstname.pack()
    LastName = lastname.pack()
    Email = email.pack()
    Password = password.pack()

    query = "insert into username_password values('" + FirstName + "', '" + LastName + "', '" + Email + "', '" + Password + "')"

    cursor.execute(query)
    data.commit()
    print("Record Saved Successfully")
    cursor.close()
    data.close()


# Buttons-
register = tk.Button(registration_window, text="REGISTER", command=insert())
clear = tk.Button(registration_window, text="Clear", command=registration_window.destroy)

register.pack()
clear.pack()

# Open Window
registration_window.mainloop()
```

This is the error I got-

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\First Project\tkinterdemo.py", line 42,
> in 
> register = tk.Button(registration_window, text="REGISTER", command=insert())   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\First
> Project\tkinterdemo.py", line 32, in insert
> sql = "insert into username_password values('" + FirstName + "', '" + LastName + "', '" + Email + "', '" + Password + "')" TypeError:
> can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

What should I do??

Comment: You need to call `firstname.get()` instead of `firstname.pack()` inside `insert()`.  Same for other `Entry` widgets.

Comment: well if i m doing that my text boxes vanish

Comment: You need to call those `.pack()` outside `insert()`. Also `command=insert()` should be `command=insert`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very insecure as it allows **sql injection**

use

```
try:
    query = "insert into username_password values (%s,%s, %s, %s)"

    cursor.execute(query,(FirstName,LastName,Email,Password))
    data.commit()
    print("Record Saved Successfully")
    cursor.close()
    data.close()    
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
```

Comment: I tried it, the error was removed but now nothing is getting recorded in the database??
What should I do?

Comment: add a error handling and see what is the problem

Comment: when I m trying to enter values and then check mysql, it is not getting recorded, and it is not showing any error while compiling

Comment: please show the create table and also don't save plain text passwords in te database, such problemis usually that you are not checking the right database

Comment: after doing this its showing FirstName cannot be Null
thats because we havent yet entered any value in the text box and it is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code:

- not calling `.pack()` on the `Entry` widgets after they are created
- calling `.pack()` instead of `.get()` inside `insert()` function
- not using *placeholder* in SQL statement to avoid SQL injection
- used `command=insert()` instead of `command=insert`. The former one will execute `insert()` immediately

Below is modified code to fix the above issues:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector

# SQL CONNECTION
try:
    data = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="login cred")
    cursor = data.cursor()
    print("Connection Successful")
except:
    print("Not Successful")

# GUI CREATION
registration_window = tk.Tk()
registration_window.geometry("1000x500")
registration_window.title("Register Yourself")

# TEXT BOX
firstname = tk.Entry(registration_window, show=None)
lastname = tk.Entry(registration_window, show=None)
email = tk.Entry(registration_window, show=None)
password = tk.Entry(registration_window, show="*")

# call pack() to show the Entry widgets
firstname.pack()
lastname.pack()
email.pack()
password.pack()

# DATABASE
def insert():
    # use .get() instead of .pack()
    FirstName = firstname.get()
    LastName = lastname.get()
    Email = email.get()
    Password = password.get()

    # use placeholders to avoid SQL injection
    query = "insert into username_password values(%s, %s, %s, %s)"

    cursor.execute(query, (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password))
    data.commit()
    print("Record Saved Successfully")
    cursor.close()
    data.close()


# Buttons-
register = tk.Button(registration_window, text="REGISTER", command=insert)  # use command=insert instead of command=insert()
clear = tk.Button(registration_window, text="Clear", command=registration_window.destroy)

register.pack()
clear.pack()

# Open Window
registration_window.mainloop()
```